# How to make the client perform a http post with php?

Tags: php, http

I'm building some efficiency tools for a crappy website. This website uses http-posts for some of it's navigation. What I need is that when a user runs a script on an url (redirect.php), I want the client to post to an url on an external site, with some variables.

I know I could do this with javascript, creating a form and posting to it, but I would prefer doing it with php if possible. It needs to be the client that get's forwarded, because they are authenticated with the website that I'm sending them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make a browser send a POST request anywhere is by making a form and submitting it, or doing equivalent trickery using Javascript. You cannot make a browser issue a POST request in response to a redirect response. There are specifications for response codes which allow "POST redirects", but no current browser implements them.